# How can Task Scheduler run multiple instances of the exe?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

How can Task Scheduler run multiple instances of the exe?
Let's say I have a daily schedule to open notepad.exe
I hope each day will open a new one, instead it will only open the first one.

If I first schdule run a .bat to run the exe, a console window will appear briefly, then I need some way to not show any console window.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you trying this on? I tested this on Windows Server 2008 R2 using your notepad.exe example (no .cmd, just launching notepad.exe). If I set the option in the task Settings "If the task is already running, then the following rule applies:" >> Run a new instance in parallel.

If I select this option then a new notepad.exe launches each time the scheduled task runs, otherwise only the first one launches it.

/edit:

For Windows XP, you could launch the executable from another process that will exit. As Ryan mentioned, you could use a .cmd batch file and the START command. If you don't want the user that's logged in to see it run, you could set the task to run as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Comment: I think there is no such setting for XP (Task Scheduler 1.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you batch file is authored correctly, then the console window should only show up for a fraction of a second, and then disappear.

```
start notepad myfirstfile.txt
start notepad mysecondfile.txt
exit /B 0
```

This shouldn't be a problem, especially since the main reason for a scheduled task is to run things when nobody's watching the computer.

If the momentary appearance of console windows is truly an unsightly crime against nature, then you need a solution which doesn't create a console window.  See [this superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/102722/run-minimized-batch-file-from-scheduler) for some scripting suggestions.

Alternatively, since stackoverflow users are programmers, you can just write a very simple .exe which does what you want:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
   ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", "myfirstfile.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
   ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", "mysecondfile.txt", NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
   return 0;
}
```